# How to prompt for input and exit if the user entered an empty string?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'm writing a program where I want to force the user to enter a word. If the user enters an empty string then the program should exit.

This is what I have so far:

```
print "Enter a word to look up: ";

chomp ($usrword = <STDIN>);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
print "Enter a word to look up: ";
my $userword = <STDIN>; # I moved chomp to a new line to make it more readable
chomp $userword; # Get rid of newline character at the end
exit 0 if ($userword eq ""); # If empty string, exit.
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Could you please explain me what does 0 and eq means ? I now that eq means equals but not quite sure about the 0

Comment: I just tried this (based on this answer), but I'm finding that the print does not always execute before the read from STDIN (so in other words, the program looks like it halts for no apperent reason) -- is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

File output is buffered by default.  Since the prompt is so short, it is still sitting in the output buffer.  You can disable buffering on STDOUT by adding this line of code before printing...

```
select((select(STDOUT), $|=1)[0]);
```