# Which non-empty string does /^$/ match?

Tags: regex, perl

In a Perl SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661379/perl-how-to-prompt-for-input-and-exit-if-user-empty-string-exit/9661651#9661651), a poster used this code to match empty strings:

```
$userword =~ /^$/; #start of string, followed immediately by end of string
```

To which [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8817/brian-d-foy) commented:

> You can't really say that because that will match one particular non-empty string.

**Question**: Which non-empty string is matched by this? Is it a string consisting of "`\r`" only?

Comment: This is the same mistake http://stackoverflow.com/q/10200057/8817 is making, too. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's check the docs, why don't we? Quote [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html),

`$`: Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)

Given

`\z`: Match only at end of string

That means `/^$/` is equivalent to `/^\n?\z/`.

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "";    say /^$/ ||0, /^\n?\z/ ||0, /^\z/ ||0;'
111

$ perl -E'$_ = "\n";  say /^$/ ||0, /^\n?\z/ ||0, /^\z/ ||0;'
110
```

Note that `/m` changes what `^` and `$` match. Under `/m`, `^` matches at the start of any "line", and `$` matches before any newline and at the end of the string.

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /^/g'
matched at 0

$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /$/g'
matched at 7
matched at 8
```

And using /m:

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /^/mg'
matched at 0
matched at 4   <-- new

$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /$/mg'
matched at 3   <-- new
matched at 7
matched at 8
```

`\A`, `\Z` and `\z` aren' t affected by `/m`:

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /\A/g'
matched at 0

$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /\z/g'
matched at 8

$ perl -E'$_ = "abc\ndef\n";  say "matched at $-[0]" while  /\Z/g'
matched at 7
matched at 8
```

Answer (score 9):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

ok("\n" =~ /^$/);
ok("\n" =~ /^\z/);
ok("\n" =~ /^\A\z/); # Better as per brian d. foy's suggestion

done_testing;
```

If you want to test if a string is empty, use `/^\z/` or see if [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) of `$str` is zero (which is what I prefer).

Output:

```
ok 1
not ok 2
not ok 3
```

Comment: If you want to test for an empty string using a regex, use `\A` too. The ^ doesn't guarantee that nothing is in front of it.

Comment: @briandfoy In the case of `^`, I am safe so long as I do not use the `m` modifier. On the other hand, `$` needs no stinking help from no outside modifier to trip me up ;-)

Comment: You aren't safe though, because Perl now has default regex flags. However, why use something in exact when you can be exact without exception?

Comment: @briandfoy - I added your suggestion as another test case. I think ikegami's excellent answer details WHY that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

The regex `/^$/` matches the non-empty string `"\n"`.

By default, Perl regular expression matching assumes that the string contains a single "line" of text.

`^` matches the beginning of the line; in the absence of a `/m` modifier, this is the same as the beginning of the string.

`$` matches either the end of the line, or before a newline at the end (that's what makes `/^$/` match the non-empty string `"\n"`).

Quoting `perldoc perlre`:

> By default, the "^" character is guaranteed to match only the
>   beginning of the string, the "$" character only the end (or before the
>   newline at the end), and Perl does certain optimizations with the
>   assumption that the string contains only one line.  Embedded newlines
>   will not be matched by "^" or "$".  You may, however, wish to treat a
>   string as a multi-line buffer, such that the "^" will match after any
>   newline within the string (except if the newline is the last character
>   in the string), and "$" will match before any newline.  At the cost of
>   a little more overhead, you can do this by using the /m modifier on
>   the pattern match operator.

Comment: If there's a good reason for the downvote, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Downvotes are of course anonymous, so we can't be sure who downvoted me. In any case, I was more concerned that there might be something wrong with my answer. (I found most of the others too indirect, going off on a tangent before actually answering the question.) No biggie.

Comment: I would upvote to balance if you included exactly WHAT $ and ^ mean (I know I can look the exact lawyering definitions in perldoc, this is merely a hint on how to improve the answer even more)

Comment: @DVK: Updated, thanks for the feedback. (And it's really about writing a good answer, not about the points.) (BTW, you have an off-by-one error in your profile.)

Comment: occupational hazard of staying eternally young. Eeek. Next thing I'll start sparkling :(

Answer (score 1):

***Script:***

```
my $str = "\n";

my $test1 = ($str =~ /^$/)   ? 1 : 0;
my $test2 = ($str =~ /\A\z/) ? 1 : 0;

print "$test1, $test2\n";
```

***Output:***

```
1, 0
```

Comment: How is this different from Sinan's answer?

Comment: @DVK - After **his** edit and adding `\A` to his answer there is pretty much no difference.

Comment: @stackoverflow Please note **I** did not edit my answer to include `\A`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür - Correction: After edit of **his** post by DVK user (which is user complaining no difference in the first comment above)...

Comment: @stackoverflow - sorry, didn't see brian d. foy's comment mentioning that there IS a difference until *after* I left the original comment.