# Coding for external user input in perl

Tags: perl, variables, input, putty, execute

I am new to perl and coding and not entirely sure where/what to search for so this question may have been asked before.

I finnished writing a program in perl and would like to know what code to use that allows me to enter a variable (name) outside the program without needing to specify it in the coding - I was told there is a way to execute the program outside of putty (I use putty) and that it asks me to enter the variable/s beforehand.

in the coding the variable is specified in the beginning as:

my $name='xxx';

after which the name is used for specifying which files to use etc. I have over 30 different names that I need to run individually so it would be much easier if I can just type it in as part of the program instead of changing the coding each time in putty.

Hope my question is clear - I'm still learning the different terms and syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: take the list in a file and iterate it over your code to get the job done

Comment: I don't understand how you are "_not entirely sure where/what to search for_" ... how about "Perl user input?" It's all over the place.  It is also not clear what you mean by mentioning "putty" -- that is a program used to connect.  With all that, if you run your script in a terminal: print out a message seeking input and then read it in: `print "Enter the name: "; $name = <STDIN>; chomp($name);`.  See, for example, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661379/how-to-prompt-for-input-and-exit-if-the-user-entered-an-empty-string), or any one of the many tutorials or books.

Comment: zdmin, as I said, I only started with perl less than a month ago so my knowledge on this subject is incerdibly limited. I was under the impression putty is used to do the editing in - apologies if I made the wrong assumption. I found several links for using <STDIN>, I probably should have mentioned this and that I have tried it, but was not able to execute it outside of the editing program - running the .pm program directly from my file directory does not give me a prompt for input, only when running from inside the editor (putty). Is it then only possible to run from inside the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

open(IN,$ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]:$!\n";
my @in = <IN>;
close(IN);

my $name='';
foreach my $in(@in){
   chomp($in);   
   $name = $in;
   ###your code here
 }
```

**your fle sample**

name1

name2

name3

**Run your programs as**

> perl program.pl filename.txt

**Update:(after OP's comment)**

```
my $name = <STDIN>;
```

this will prompt for a user input.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Problem is the list keeps growing/changing and I would like to be able to run them one by one. Is there no way to request a prompt where you enter the name beforehand?

Comment: Think twice about doing that. It's theoretically possible, but actually a terrible idea.